# Different template module on DNN

Tags: templates, module, dotnetnuke

I'm hosting some websites on DotNetNuke 5. So I have one portal per client, with it own skin.

I tried, for example, to personalize the "html/text" module to include some predefined style like "blue title", "grey title", etc.

But if I do those modifications, it will be available on all portals... and I don't want website1 see website2' style.

I hope you understand my question. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Install the DnnWerk RadEditorProvider for your site, this will get you the ability to set a Rad template per portal.
2. Upgrade to DotNetNuke 6.0 which includes DnnWerk's provider by default.